# pouchdb, how to add custom headers to HTTP sync request?

Tags: pouchdb

How to add custom headers to HTTP sync request in pouchdb? Following is not working. I am using middleware proxy which requires additional headers. I need to add following 2 headers (Authorization and APPID).

```
var opts = {live: true, complete: syncError, withCredentials:true, headers: {Authorization : 'Basic ' + Base64.encode("user:pass"), 'APPID': 1001}};

db.replicate.to(remoteCouch, opts);
```

Answer (score 3):

According to [the official documentation](http://pouchdb.com/api.html#options), you can add custom headers (and more) by using the `ajax` option. Example:

```
var db = new PouchDB('http://example.com/dbname', {
  ajax: {
    cache: false,
    timeout: 10000,
    headers: {
      'X-Some-Special-Header': 'foo'
    },
    username: 'mysecretusername',
    password: 'mysecretpassword'
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Using a object worked:

```
var remoteCouch = new PouchDB('https://serverurl', {headers:{ "APPCID": 1001} });
db.replicate.to(remoteCouch, opts);
```

From: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/pouchdb/zPQqKzJjQ-M